# Bound on $\|ABv\|$ in terms of $\|Av\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

I have a Hilbert space $H$ with:

- An unbounded self-adjoint operator $T$.
- Another unbounded operator $S$ such that $S=PTP^{-1}$, where $P$ is a bounded invertible operator (not necessarily unitary).

I am interested in proving a bound of the following type - for a given $\lambda\in \mathbb R, v\in H$:
$$\|(S-\lambda)v\|\leq C\|(T-\lambda)v\|$$
for some $C>0$, which might depend on $\lambda$ ($\lambda$ is assumed to be in the resolvent set of $T$ and $S$).

What I tried to do (denoting the norm of $P$ by $a$):
$$\|(S-\lambda)v\|=\|(PTP^{-1}-\lambda)v\|\leq a\|(TP^{-1}-P^{-1}\lambda)v\|$$
$$=a\|(TP^{-1}-\lambda P^{-1})v\|=a\|(T-\lambda)P^{-1}v\|$$

This is almost what I want. If I could pull $P^{-1}$ out of the norm, this would exactly give a bound of the type I am looking for. But since $T$ and $P^{-1}$ do not commute, I cannot do this, and I am wondering if there is still a way to obtain a helpful inequality.

I can try to write $TP^{-1}=P^{-1}T+[T,P^{-1}]$, and then maybe try to find bounds on the commutator as well. But I do not know too much about the commutator, and it feels like there should be a simpler way I am missing.

Any advice? I can try to give more information about the given operators if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that's false, because of the case when $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ but not of $S$.

Comment: @LL3.14 Note that $\lambda$ is in the resolvent set of both operators. Moreover, since $S=PTP^{-1}$, they have the same spectrum.

Comment: Yes, but not the same eigenvectors!

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes but again, $\lambda$ is assumed to be outside the spectrum of both.

Comment: Oh, ok, can $C$ depend on $\lambda$?

Comment: @LL3.14 Yes, just not on $\phi$. That's a good point, I'll it to the post.

Comment: There is a problem with domains. If $v\in D(T)$ you have no guarantee that $v\in D(S).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. First notice that $S-\lambda = P(T-\lambda)P^{-1}$, so up to replacing $T$ by $T-\lambda$ and $S$ by $S-\lambda$, one can assume that $\lambda = 0$ and $S$ and $P$ are invertible.

Now take as an example $H = L^2(\Bbb R^2)$ and $Tv(x) = (1+|x_1|^2)\,v(x)$ where $x=(x_1,x_2)$. Then taking the bounded operator $Pv(x) = v(x_2,x_1)$ gives $Sv(x) = (1+|x_2|^2)\,v(x)$ and your inequality would correspond to
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^2} v(x)^2 \,(1+|x_2|^2)\,\mathrm d x \leq C \int_{\Bbb R^2} v(x)^2 \,(1+|x_1|^2)\,\mathrm d x,
$$
which is obviously false in general: take for example $v(x) = \varphi(x_1)\,(1+|x_2|^2)^{-1/2}$ with $\varphi$ smooth and compactly supported.

Comment: Too bad, thanks for the nice answer. It is surprising that even when $P$ is unitary (as in your example) such a bound does not necessarily hold. It seems that the problem is that $T$ is unbounded, and so $\|TPv\|$ can be arbitrarily large compared to $\|Tv\|$ (and vice versa). I'll try to think if something can be done for my specific case.

Comment: A way to think of it is to say: $S$ and $T$ are both unbounded, could $S/T$ be bounded ... and that's not true if they are unbounded in different "directions"